# GTA 5: Does the FIB building blow up in the rooftop entry choice?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I chose the rooftop entry choice in this mission. I heard that in the fire truck one the building blows up. Does the FIB building get damaged in the rooftop entry choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

> The helicopter that flies you over the building and drops you gets shot down and it crashes into the building.